# How to Install Non-Hardware Device Driver - Win10

Tags: windows, driver

I have software-only device driver I compiled from the Windows WDK samples (simgpio.sys). How do I install this? All the instructions I've found are for hardware drivers.

**UPDATE 7/2/20**
I made partial progress. If I Ctrl-RtClick on the INF file, there is a menu item "Install". This seems to work: "The operation completed successfully". It still doesn't show up in DeviceManager, maybe because it has no associated hardware (?)..

Answer (score 0):

Run *cmd.exe* as administrator and enter the following commands.

Create driver service

```
sc create YOUR_SERVICE_NAME binpath= "YOUR_DRIVER_PATH_NAME" type=kernel start=demand
```

Start driver service

```
sc start YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

Stop driver service

```
sc stop YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

Delete driver service

```
sc delete YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

Comment: I believe this only works if I have an EXE file. I don't - just .INF and .SYS files. Years back, If I recall correctly, Device Manager had a feature to install an arbitrary .INF without hardware but can't find it now.